# How to detect bullet holes on a shooting target

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-recognition

I'm currently working on my first assignment in image processing (using OpenCV in Python, but I'm open to any libraries and languages). My assignment is to calculate a precise score (to tenths of point) of one to several shooting holes in an image uploaded by a user. The issue is that the image uploaded by the user can be taken on different backgrounds (although it will never match the rest of the target mean colors). Due to this, I have ruled out most of the solutions found on the internet and most of the solutions I could come up with.

## ***Summary of my problem***

### Bullet holes identification:

- bullet holes can be on different backgrounds
- bullet holes can overlap
- single bullet holes will always be of similar size (there is only one type of caliber used on all of the calculated shooting targets)

  - I'm able to calculate a very precise radius of the shooting hole

### Shooting targets:

- there are two types of shooting targets that my app is going to calculate (images provided below)
- photos of the shooting targets can be taken in different lighting conditions

#### Shooting target 1 example:

[image: Shooting target 1 example]

#### Shooting target 2 example:

[image]

#### Shooting target examples to find bullet holes in:

- [shooting target example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kbpgq.jpg)
- [shooting target example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRjp7.jpg)
- [shooting target example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUgwY.jpg)
- [shooting target example 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9oSO.jpg)
- [shooting target example 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei5jq.jpg)

### What I tried so far:

1. **Color segmentation**

   - due to the reasons mentioned above
2. **Difference matching**

   - to be able to actually compare the target images (empty and fired on), I have written an algorithm that crops the target by its outer largest circle (its radius + bullet size in pixels)
   - after that, I have probably tried all of the ways of images comparison found on the internet
   - for example: brute force matching, histogram comparisons, feature matching and many more
   - I failed here mostly because the colors on both compared images were a bit different and also because one of the images was sometimes taken in a slight angle and therefore the circles weren't overlapping and they were calculated as differences
3. **Hough circles algorithm**

   - since I know the radius (in pixels) of the shots on the target I thought I could simply detect them using this algorithm
   - after several hours/days of playing with parameters of HoughCircles function, I figured it would never work on all of the uploaded images without changing the parameters based on the uploaded image
4. **Edge detection and finding contours of the bullet holes**

   - I have tried two edge detection methods (Canny and Sobel) while playing with image smoothening  algorithms (like blurring, bilateral filtering, metamorphization, etc..)
   - after that, I have tried to find all of the contours in the edge detected image and filter out the circles of the target with a similar center point
   - this seemed like the solution at first, but on several test images it wouldn't work properly :/

**At this point, I have ran out of ideas and therefore came here for any kind of advice or an idea that would push me further. Is it possible that there simply isn't a solution to such complicated shooting target recognition or am I just too inexperienced to come up with it?**

Thank you in advance for any help.

Edit: I know I could simply put a single color paper behind the shooting target and find the bullets that way. This is not how I want the app to work thought and therefore it's not a valid solution to my problem.

Comment: Place your shooting target templates with the holes on a paper with green (or blue or red) background. Then extract the green image. Now you can do houghcircles and only get the shooting holes circle. You can apply the same logic with white circles but getting the image processing is a bit trickier. In photoshop you'd be adjusting the curves and place them really high. So grey and black turn to black but grey and white turn to black and white.

Comment: This is unfortunately not usable in my case. Its unwanted for the user to carry a green (or any different color) paper with him at all times during his shootings. For learning purposes, I tried to do it the exact same way you described and it worked. It's not a solution to my assignment though. Anyway, thanks for your response.

Comment: When you extract the green image you get a "black and white" image. That same logic you can also apply to bullet holes with a white or black background. The image processing is a bit trickier but works on the same pricniple

Comment: I understand, but as I said, the user can upload an image with any kind of background color. The algorithm would therefore need to find the color and work that way, which seems impossible to me.

Comment: In photoshop you can do some more advanced curve where pixels with a similar color to the target template is converted to white and anything else is converted to black. You will have to search for a tool which can apply those color conversion curves to your image.

Comment: I actually already tried to find a way of doing this in an algorithm but unfortunately couldn't find it anywhere. Any idea on how to do this in code?

Comment: If I am wrong please correct me. There is an area which user will shoot and you wanna detect which part it is. So why dont you look at the difference of that area before shooting and after shooting. The different pixel means shooted???

Comment: Basically yes, I have a photo of the template of the shooting target (which is taken with different lighting, different resolution etc..) and then a user uploads a taken photo of his shooting target after shooting at it. I tried to go with a similar approach like you mentioned here, but failed since the pixels are of different values. As I described in my question, hopefully in good detail.

Comment: @JakubS does the centre of the shooting board is always at the centre of the image? (with small accepted tolerance), and the scores always has the same numbers from 1 to 8 ??

Comment: @BelalHomaidan yes, the center of the target will always be somewhat in the center of the image, due to my algorithm that crops the image by the outer circle of the shooting target. As of the scores, yes and no, the targets have circles with values from 1-8 but the maximum score is 10.9 (10 when touching the dot in the middle of the circle, or the smallest circle in the other target type), 10.9 if the center of the bullet hole matches the center point of the target. I'm able to calculate the score, but I'm not able to reliably detect the shooting holes. That is why I made this question.

Comment: did you try edge detection / contour detection in combination with template matching like chamfer matching? What exactly is the problem in your edge detection approach? False positives or false negatives or both?

Comment: I actually didn't try chamfer matching but only the simplest template matching in opencv, so thanks for that idea, although it seems really complicated for me and there isn't much tutorials on it out there. In my edge detection approach, I have detected both false positives and false negatives while testing it on several different images. Sometimes the edge of the shooting hole wasn't complete and it seemed impossible to close the edge and use it that way. I would really appreciate it if u provided me some code example for the chamfer matching with edge/contour detection or some kind of guide.

Comment: Have you found a soulution for this yet? I am currently stugglig the same issue. Although I do have faith in houghcircles to work. Configuration and kalibration is key here.

Comment: Do your bullet holes all look the same ? if so a simple cross-correlation algorithm with some samples could at least detect some…

Answer (score 1):

Just to compare before and after images to identify the difference between those. And calculate hole-edge's shortest distance from calculated/analyzed centerpoint of target?

Comment: The phrasing of your answer is distracting. You are attempting to answer the question at the top of the page. Starting a sentence seemingly in the middle and ending your post with a "?" can easily mislead other users into thinking that this is not an answer according to [answer].

Comment: Did you read "What I tried so far - Difference Matching"? What do you suggest to solve the issues listed there?

Comment: What does that mean? Did you mean this post to be an answer according to [answer]? In that case please [edit] to make that more obvious. If did not mean to answer and only want to discuss or clarify something please understand that you would need the commenting privilege for that. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead So if this is not a correct answer please delete it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).